# Displaying firstname and last name in the same column in react-table-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have an API rendering some user data, first- and last name etc.:

```
users = [{
  firstname: 'Peter',
  lastname: 'Pan'
  address: 'someAddress'
},
  firstname: 'Winnie',
  lastname: 'thePoo'
  address: 'someOtherAddress'
}]
```

Now, I would like to display the name in the same column in the react-table-2 to enable searching for both first- and last name.
What is the best way to do this? I have tried formatting the data through the "formatter" property, but it does not seem to work well when searching.

Any ideas? I would like to avoid changing the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const data = [
  {
    firstname: 'Peter',
    lastname: 'Pan',
    address: 'someAddress'
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Winnie',
    lastname: 'thePoo',
    address: 'someOtherAddress'
  }
]

class TwoFielSameColumn extends Component{

    render(){
      const finalData = data.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        fullName: `${item.firstname} ${item.lastname}` || "",
      }))
    
      return(
        <div>
          {finalData.map((q) => <div>{q.fullName}</div>)}
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default TwoFielSameColumn;
```

Use finalData of tabledata

Answer (score 1):

While defining the column:

```
...
{
    Header: "Name",
    accessor: "name",
    Cell: ( {row} ) => {return (`${row.original.firstname} ${row.original.lastname}`)}
},
```

Since I was using server side pagination and filters I am not sure how would it behave when we use filters. Sorting was not working so I thought. May be someone can elaborate it.